# Add subview in interfaceBuilder

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to add a label to UIView and I would like to preview it in InterfaceBuilder, however it doesn't seem to work. not only I don't see label but It also doesn't append one to view hierarchy

```
@IBDesignable
class UIFloatingLabelInput: UIView {

/*
// Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

let Label : UILabel?


func AddLabel(){
    Label?.text = "Hello World"
    Label?.center = CGPoint(x: self.center.x, y: self.center.y)
    self.addSubview(Label!)
    
}

override init(frame: CGRect){
    //Init vars
    Label = UILabel(frame: frame)
    //Call Initializer
    super.init(frame: frame)
    
    AddLabel()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder){
    //Init vars
    Label = UILabel(coder: coder)
    //CallInitializer
    super.init(coder: coder)
    
    AddLabel()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    AddLabel()
}
```

}

but it doesn't work in IB, but works fine on a device.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to give your label frame to make it work in IB

```
required init?(coder: NSCoder){
    //Init vars
    Label = UILabel(coder: coder)
    
    //CallInitializer
    super.init(coder: coder)
    

    //Give your label a frame
    Label.frame = bounds
    
    AddLabel()
}
```

Comment: you can't use bounds prior to calling super.init since it is not set. but I do get what you mean.